# Light measurement with accurate nanosecond synchronization

Tags: java, javascript, c++, synchronization

Is it possible to synchronize two computers in a nanosecond level? What I want is to measure the distance that a signal has travelled. As known light travels really fast. By knowing that the signal went off at 1.0000000001 seconds and reached the destination point at 1.00000000021 seconds we can calculate the distance which is my problem.

I found `window.performance.now()` in java but i am not sure if synchronization can be achieved by using the internet and how is it possible. Thanks for bothering :)

Comment: Not without special hardware, no. That kind of accuracy is *very* difficult to achieve. GPS is already quite accurate, and uses specialized hardware, yet only gets 14 ns of accuracy at best. It's not likely  that you can do much better without lots of money. And if you use the internet, the chances of synchronizing two computers to nanosecond accuracy is pretty much zero.

Comment: No, this will most certainly not be possible using the internet. And typicl operating systems will not let you measure time anywhere near the required accuracy.

Comment: With specialist hardware you can measure sub-micro-second timings.  However, if you want to know the exact latency of a line, you are best to use devices design to test cables.  These can give you the exact length and latency more accurately than a computer can (as computers are not designed to do this)

Comment: E.g. you will find it hard to write on one machine and read it under 5 micro-seconds reliably using low latency hardware.  Looking for sub-micro-second delays this way will be pretty unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer...

Theoretically, the answer is "yes". However, a nanosecond is such a short period of time that synchronizing computers with nanosecond accuracy/precision is an extraordinarily difficult task that would almost certainly require you to use specialized hardware and knowledge to achieve.

[This](http://www.allanstime.com/Publications/DWA/Science_Timekeeping/TheScienceOfTimekeeping.pdf) paper dives a bit into how timekeeping works, and might given an idea about how difficult timing might be. A quick Command-F seach for "nanosecond" reveal the following tidbits:

> The current best accuracy for the determination of the second results in a time error
>   of ±0.3 nanoseconds (billionths of a second) per day
>
> [NIST and USNO], in diverse and non-overlapping ways, supply time for the United States and for the BIPM, and their time scales are usually synchronous to within about 20 nanoseconds
>
> ...combining these two independent error sources [USNO time and GPS time] yields a real-time potential uncertainty for UTC available from GPS at about the 14-ns level.
>
> LASSO has been successfully tested in 1992 between McDonald (Texas) and Grasse (France), with a stability of 100 picoseconds and an accuracy on the order of 1 nanosecond.

etc. (I hope I didn't misquote anything....)

But the general idea is that nanosecond accuracy and/or synchronization is *really* hard to achieve. This paper is pretty old (1997), and I'm not sure of the accuracy of those statements, but I think you get the idea. Involving the internet is just going to making accurate synchronization essentially impossible, as you have no control over where your signal goes and/or the path it takes, so the delay becomes impossible to predict.

Jim Garrison illustrates the difficulty of achieving nanosecond accuracy much better than the quotes I have here, but I thought they might be interesting to read.

---

I did find something called the [White Rabbit Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_White_Rabbit_Project), which is an effort by CERN and some other collaborators to create an Ethernet-based network for data transfer and synchronization. One of the goals is sub-nanosecond synchronization accuracy, which might be of interest to you. I still believe this would require rather interesting hardware, but it might be possible to avoid extremely specialized hardware using this.

Answer (score 0):

While system timers can be defined to have nanosecond *precision* (number of significant digits) there's no way to achieve that level of *accuracy* with inexpensive hardware.  You're playing very close to the limits imposed by relativity and the speed of light.

Light in a vacuum travels about 1 foot per nanosecond, and an electrical impulse in a copper wire goes about half that speed.  Using your numbers we have

```
End         1.000_000_000_21
Start       1.000_000_000_1

Difference  0.000_000_000_11
```

That's 110 *pico* seconds (or 0.11ns), or a distance of about 1.3 inches.  Resolution at this level is possible, but it takes specialized laboratory equipment called an interferometer.